# Sharepoint data view web part

Tags: sharepoint

I'm looking for a good data view web part that will allow me to specify;

- The connection string in web.config

  - Alternatively, take the connection string from a web part connection
- The SQL to execute, taking parameters from a web part connection

And feature

- Paging and sorting
- Filtering

Any suggestions?

Cheers
Tony

Answer (score 0):

YOu can you the DataFormWebPart. design it in SharePoint Designer. YOu can speciy datasources there too.

Answer (score 0):

You could write custom webpart and get exactly the functionality you want. For a quick solution you could write regular ASP.NET user control and use [SmartPart](http://www.codeplex.com/smartpart) to deploy it as a WebPart.